# How can I excute SQL queries in Access 2007 file from C# Web Service?

Tags: web-services, ms-access-2007

We want to have a hosted C# web service in IIS that I can pass to its method SOL Query and it execute the query on a Access 2007 DB file that exist in the same server that contain Web service and return data.

We already use the following code

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" 
  CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" 
  Class="Service" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet ExecuteQuery(string sqlQuery) 
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
             @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
             @"C:\Folder\Database2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);            
        return ds;
    }

}
```

but when we call this method the page is just shown as in Load (in progress) but without any return of data or Exception.

Comment: Passing a sql query to a web service to execute is just asking to be abused ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May I suggest a few improvements to your design and code structure?

**1.** Re-evaluate the reason for making this a web service. Can you compile this into a class library assembly (.dll) and reference it from other projects? The overhead, or time cost, of making the web service call is much larger than a reference to another library. Yes, there are configuration issues with Access that you'll have to deal with.

**2.** Reconsider the reason that you want a DataSet returned on each call. Here's an excellent article on the drawbacks of ADO.NET DataSets: [www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125132705/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx)

**3.** Do not execute any string given to you without evaluating or parameterizing it first. I understand the desire to create a layer that will handle all the database querying for you, and you should be applauded for that idea. The code, as presented, will create a more dangerous situation however, as it doesn't check for any malformed statements, etc. So the suggestion is to NOT execute any string that is passed to you. Perhaps this web service is INSIDE your LAN only, and perhaps you trust that all calls will be honest and non-destructive. We might think that all internal activity is good, but as soon as an employee turns bad, you are opening the possibility for inside sabotage.

What happens when someone calls your webservice like this:

```
ExecuteQuery("DELETE FROM Customers")
```

or

```
ExecuteQuery("UPDATE Employee SET Salary = 250000 WHERE ID= 9")
```

or

```
ExecuteQuery("SELECT Salary WHERE EmployeePosition = 'CEO'")
```

**4.** Create one new webmethod for each function that you want the layer to expose. For example, instead of the client calling

```
ExecuteQuery("SELECT ID, CustomerName FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerName")
```

do this:

```
public List<Customer> ListAllCustomers()
```

Consider creating methods like this:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
```

or

```
public void UpdateEmployeeSalary(string id, double salary)
```

**5.** Put your Access connection string into an `app.config` file. Reference `System.Configuration` and use `ConfigurationManager`. load it everytime when the query is called. It's a bit of a performance hit, but really the maintenance workload is zero when changing the directory path or name of the .mdb file.

```
  private string GetConnectionString()
        {
           //do some more checking on whether the value exists as well, instead of just returning it!
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAccessDB"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your usefull suggestions , but in my situatio i really need to make it as a web service as we have a sharepoint site and we make our reports using Access 2007 which can do SQL querires on Sharepoint lists and we already do that but when the file of ACCESS 2007 is exist in Sharepoint server and any query access files the sharepoint site become sooooo slow so we decide to make the access db files in another server and query it from sharepoint server using Web serivice so we should use web service not a Class Library ... i wish i able to explain the full problem we face

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
         @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
         @"C:\Folder\Database2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);            
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Do this unless you like resource leaks.